# Is there a way to align TextView vertically center with ImageView in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `RelativeLayout` with `ImageView` and `TextView` on the left and `ImageView` and `TextView` on the right.

but they are not aligning well with the ImageView. I want it to align vertically center to the image next to the text view

This is how it looks at the moment:

[image]

The RelativeLayout I'm using is this:

**Question**

How can I make the `TextView` align well with the `ImageView`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/leftIcon"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/trash" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftIcon"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:text="some text 1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/trash" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="some text 2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "align well " ? what exactly are you going to achieve ?

Comment: have you tried `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`?

Comment: I assume you want the images to align with the baseline of the text (and not with the bottom of the textView). `android:layout_alignBaseline` is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @FarhadFaghihi I am trying to align the TextView vertically center to the Image next to it

Comment: I've tried all three suggestions `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` or `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` or `android:layout_alignBaseline` but neither works.

Comment: @birdy : Have you tried `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` for both of the ImageViews and both of the TextViews? They all need to have that attribute.

Comment: @squonk that worked. There is still slight alignment issue but I think that might be because of the icon size.

Comment: I recommed that you use "drawableLeft" property of the TextView, instead of imageview and try to adjust the text using paddingTop and paddingBottom. Moreover, you'll save at least two imageviews and a little bit of process time for rendering the layout!

Answer (score 0):

```
hi try this code i think it will help you : 

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/leftIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="some text 1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:text="some text 2"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem...

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/leftIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="some text 1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="some text 2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/leftIcon"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tv2"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftIcon"
        android:text="some text 1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
        android:text="some text 2"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: May I know the reason for -1

Comment: Yes - In what way does anything you've posted address issues with aligning the TextViews  center verically? Read the question title.

Comment: No it doesn't look good. To start with you seem to have decided the OP wants `ic_launcher` as their drawable instead of the `trash` drawable. You've added the `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` attribute to the second `ImageView` but not the first then you've added `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` to the second `TextView` but not the first.